# !say discord.py rewrite command

Tags: discord, discord.py

This is my code

```
@bot.command()
async def say(ctx, message=None):
  await ctx.message.delete()
  await ctx.send(message)
```

However, if I do !!say I’m a dog, the bot will say only I’m

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because space is an argument separator. If you want to have an argument with spaces use `*` in your function. Like this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def say(ctx,*,message=None):
  await ctx.message.delete()
  await ctx.send(message)
```